# set javascript div id to increasing var

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables, auto-increment

I have a looping form in PHP that I want to submit through javascript.  The problem is that each of the ids seem to need their own separate javascript submit code.

PHP CODE:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < $num) {
    $j = $i + 1;
    echo "<form id='form".$j."' name='form3' method='post' action='post.php'>
    <input type ='checkbox' name='box1' value = 'useless' >&nbsp;Useless</input>
    <input type='submit' name= 'submit' id='submit' value='Submit' />
    </form>";
    $i++;
}
```

Javascript which doesn't work:

```
var x = 2;
var y = '<?php echo $num; ?>';
while (x <= y) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#form" + x).on("change", "input:checkbox", function () {
            $("#form" + x).submit();
        });
    });
    x++;
```

Comment: you need to increase x inside your while loop, if you console log it, is is an infinite loop, but on the same elements.

Comment: php in js? how do u call the js function? and what expected result? what is your current result?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating a submit button for each form but you seem to want to trigger the submit when the checkbox is changed, a simpler solution might be:

```js
$('[name="box1"]').change(function() {
      $(this).next().click();
});


// this is just here to demonstrate that all of the forms will not be submitted at once in response to your comment
$('form').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();    
      $('#result').append('submitted form with id '+ $(this).attr('id')+'<br>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="post.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="box1" value="useless"/>Useless
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>



<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="post.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="box1" value="useless"/>Useless
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


<form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" action="post.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="box1" value="useless"/>Useless
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<br>
<div id="result"><div>
```

BTW, `<input type ='checkbox' name='box1' value = 'useless' >&nbsp;Useless</input>`  should be `<input type ='checkbox' name='box1' value = 'useless' />&nbsp;Useless`.

Input is a [void element](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/html5/void-elements-html5/) and does not have a closing tag

Comment: but then it would submit all the the looped forms, that isn't the only value being submitted there is a hidden variable value that when posted will update mysql column only of the form submitted.  If i did it like you are suggesting, it would update all of them (27), not just the one.

Comment: @Celeste That is not correct, the submit button is inside of a form, when that button is clicked, it will submit the parent form only, it will not submit the other 26 forms. I have updated my answer to demonstrate this

Comment: the submit button isn't triggering the javascript, it's sending it to post.php

Comment: @Celeste The submit button is not triggering what javascript? In you original attempt you had `$("#form" + x).submit();` which would have submitted the native form which is exactly what this code does. What javascript are you trying to trigger?

Comment: The javascript u gave me.  Im using the original php code up top with this:$(document).ready(function () {
$('[name="box1"]').change(function() {
$(this).next().click();
});
});

Comment: Yeah, I see that but what Im saying is that "In you original attempt you had $("#form" + x).submit(); which would have submitted the native form which is exactly what this code does. ". But here you say "the submit button isn't triggering the javascript, it's sending it to post.php". That's exactly what submitting a form does. Are you wanting to submit the form variables via `ajax`? If so you have not mentioned that anywhere

Comment: @Celeste do you need the the submit button at all or will checking the box be the only thing that submits the ajax?

Comment: ideally checking the box.